# How to rewrite code to work for newest Selenium version (DeprecationWarning: executable_path)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to setup an Instagram follow-bot and I keep getting the same error. I already figured out why it's triggered but I'm not sure how to implement it into my code.

I believe the error is happening because the command is depreciated after version 4.0 of Selenium. I need help rewriting this line:     `browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe')` to work with Selenium's current version.

**Error:**

`DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe') Message: invalid argument: invalid locator (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.65)`

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time, random
from threading import Thread

# Profile you need to follow:
target_profile = 'target'

# Time between follows:
delay = 10

def auth(browser, username, password):
    try:
        browser.get('https://instagram.com')
        time.sleep(random.randrange(2,4))

        input_username = browser.find_element("username")
        input_password = browser.find_element("password")

        input_username.send_keys(username)
        time.sleep(random.randrange(1,2))
        input_password.send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(random.randrange(1,2))
        input_password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        browser.quit()

def follow(username, password, target):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
    browser.set_window_size(350, 900)
    auth(browser, username, password)
    try:
        time.sleep(random.randrange(8,10))
        browser.get('https://instagram.com/' + target)
        time.sleep(random.randrange(3,6))
        try:
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section').find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Message']")
            print(f'[{username}] already follow "{target}"')
            time.sleep(random.randrange(2,4))
            browser.quit()
        except:
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section').find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Follow']").click()
            time.sleep(random.randrange(3,6))
            browser.get('https://instagram.com/' + target)
            time.sleep(random.randrange(3,6))
            try:
                browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section').find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Message']")
                print(f'[{username}] successfully follow "{target}"')
                time.sleep(random.randrange(2,4))
                browser.quit()
            except:
                print(f'[{username}] didnt follow "{target}"')
                time.sleep(random.randrange(2,4))
                browser.quit()
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        browser.quit()



f = open('bots.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
    log = line.split(':')
    follow(log[0], log[1], target_profile)
    time.sleep(delay)
```

I tried executing a depreciated command after Selenium version 4.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Selenium `v4.6.0` or above, you don't need to set the `driver.exe` path. A new tool known as Selenium Manager within Selenium will handle the browser and browser drivers.

You can simply replace the below line:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
```

To:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

It should work and you should be able to get rid of that deprecated error.

Reference: [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/#:%7E:text=Selenium%20Manager%20is%20a%20CLI,driver%20manager%20is%20being%20used.)

### Update

Change below line:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath
```

To:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "<your xpath>")
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Now I get the following Error:

`Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.65)`

Comment: Check the updated answer. Since you upgraded to latest selenium, the syntax slightly changes, refer above and change accordingly in all places in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = option)
```

just remove executable path argument. selenium will auto detect chromedriver from same directory.